# Proving or Disproving: Proximal mapping of f = gradient of g

Tags: optimization, continuity, vector-analysis

I am given that the function f is convex, closed and proper. I am trying to prove or disprove the claim "There exists g convex and differentiable such that the proximal mapping of f is equal to the gradient of g."

I believe its true, however not sure how to back this claim.

Comment: It will be more likely that the community provides help if you show your efforts :)